# How to see the deployment progress via aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I created a deployment using AWS cli:

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name systest1 --deployment-group-name TEST --s3-location bucket=artifacts,bundleType=zip,key=APP.zip
```

and I got the out as

```
{
    "deploymentId": "d-559F8S41O"
}
```

How can I see the status of the deployment?? I believe

> aws deploy get-deployment

will show us the status but it will not show continuous progress. Actually, I am using AWS cli so use don't have to go on AWS console and check the deployment status instead he will get the result on gitlab-ci output only. Any suggestion??

Comment: There is a waiter command that will wait for the deployment to complete. While it will not show a progress bar or status, it can be used to check the final status of the deployment and also wait for the deployment to complete before proceeding. The details about this command can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/wait/deployment-successful.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the below CLI command to get the status:

```
aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id d-52EZVE6PC --query "deploymentInfo.[status, creator]" --output text
```